# Openssl convert .PEM containing only RSA Private Key to .PKCS12

Tags: openssl, rsa, pem, pkcs#12

Currently I have a .PEM file containing only a private key. I need to convert this file into a .PKCS12 file. Currently I'm trying to use openssl to achieve this and I'm running into some problems.

The .PEM file I'm using is of the form:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Some key

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I use the following Openssl command to attempt to convert this .PEM file into a .PKCS12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey file.pem -out file.p12
```

The console then hangs with the message:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state -done
```

What am Im doing wrong?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: So far you've only accepted one answer to any of your questions, and that was your own answer!

Comment: The pkcs12 file typically contains a certificate chain plus the private key for the leaf certificate of the chain. In its simplest form it contains one self-signed certificate plus the associated private key. You need to create a certificate with your public key, and that certificate must contain the fields that your consuming application is expecting.

Answer (score 45):

I ran into this problem and resolved it by adding the `-nocerts` option after export.  My guess regarding the cause of the "freeze up" is that openssl is probably trying to read additional input from the console.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nocerts -inkey your.private.key.pem -out your.private.key.p12
```

Comment: @sliq..could you please have a look on my question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149979/pem-key-generation-format-encoding-errors

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to provide the certificate as well, not only the private key:

> ```
> openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privatekey.pem -in certificate.cer -out
> bothAsPKCS12.p12
> ```

Comment: True. In my experience, `-in` (e.g. .cer/.crt) and `-inkey` (e.g. .key) must be provided.