# How to generate .p12 certificate for HTTPS on Tomcat from keys

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, ssl, tomcat

I want to make my connection secured, so I bought some keys from my domain provider. I have experience with self-signed certificate and know that my Spring Boot requires .p12 key, but now I have this keys

- Public certificate
- Root certificate
- Intermediate certificate
- Certificate Signing Request
- Private certificate

  All this certificates are .txt files. Can somebody explain please how to transform this 5 files into .p12 key, so I can use HTTPS one my tomcat server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openssl convert .PEM containing only RSA Private Key to .PKCS12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994116/openssl-convert-pem-containing-only-rsa-private-key-to-pkcs12)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I need certificate for production